# Jenkins validates the JMeter build as successful when it’s actually failed

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I have similar issue, that blocks me. I need to run my JMeter tests with Jenkins. But Jenkins validates the JMeter build as successful when it’s actually failed. I wonder what I am doing wrong so that the jmeter won't return fail when an assertion fails.
I run a Windows Batch script calling jMeter. Here's how:

**COMMAND LINE**

```
cd C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin
jmeter -n -c -t C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Automation\WIP\Test-page.jmx -l C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Automation\WIP\Test-page.xml
```

And saves the results in .xml to validate the report with the Performance plugin (v 2.0) and Jenkins ver. 2.32.1

**CONSOLE**

```
Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Automation\WIP\Test-page.jmx
Starting the test @ Fri Dec 30 11:05:58 GMT 2016 (1483095958952)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =      1 in 00:00:00 =    3.1/s Avg:   206 Min:   206 Max:   206 Err:     1 (100.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Dec 30 11:05:59 GMT 2016 (1483095959326)
... end of run


Performance: Recording JMeter reports 'C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Automation\WIP\Test-page.xml'
Performance: Parsing JMeter report file 'C:\Jenkins\jobs\Test demo\builds\3\performance-reports\JMeter\Test-page.xml'.
Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 0% sets the build as unstable
Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 0% sets the build as failure


Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see I have 1 error. But the Performance plugin sets the build to success.

**PLUGIN SETTINGS**
[performance plugin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDyvm.png)

**Jmeter properties**

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
```

**TEST CASE**
[Test-page.jmx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B34F0YksxmiwSXNic2lpZlRiSnM/view?usp=sharing)

Attempts I tried and didn’t work for me:

1. older version of the Performance plugin (v 1.11 and v.16)
2. .jtl format
3. .xml
4. .csv
5. adding "echo" to the command line in the end
6. setting `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true`

Ran out of ideas how to make the Performance plugin count the errors and raise the "Failed" flag :(

Comment: maybe, you are facing a bug. link https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37988

Comment: in that case, can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: I don't know any work around for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Set "Use error thresholds on single build" from 0 to `1`.

This should mean that the jenkins build fails if at least 1 error is in your JMeter test case, where a 0 ignores the error count (If I remember this correctly).

Comment: I am totally new to Jenkins and Jmeter, but in all the tutorials I've seen, the they set 0 for the build to fail with even one error. I tried with values like 1; 42; 100 but no difference. I guess it's really a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a Performance Plugin issue, I believe you should report it via [Jenkins Bug Tracker](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/)

In the meantime to work this around I would suggest returning non-zero exit code for the JMeter build step, the fastest and the easiest way is running your JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper. Taurus has powerful [Pass/Fail Criteria subsystem](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) where you can define the conditions of your build failure. If the condition will be met Taurus execution step will be finished with code `3`. Jenkins is smart enough to automatically fail command-line tasks with non-zero exit code.

Minimal working Taurus config file:

```
---
execution:
  scenario: my-test

scenarios:
  my-test:
    script: C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Automation\WIP\Test-page.jmx

services:
- module: passfail
  criteria:
  - succ<100%, stop as failed
```

More information, if needed: [Meetup Recap on Using Taurus to Automate JMeter and Jenkins Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/meetup-recap-using-taurus-automate-jmeter-and-jenkins-tests)

You can also change JMeter exit code directly form the JMeter test via i.e. [JSR223 Scripting Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like:

```
if (some condition) {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

but in this case you won't have much flexibility in terms of setting failure criteria

Answer (score 0):

I set my **Select evaluation mode** to standard mode, Set the radio button on **Error Threshold** and set **Unstable** and **Failed** to 1